Driving sc_signal using sc_in, sc_out using sc_signal
Given a wrapper module with some exports (sc_in, sc_out)
I would like to drive multiple core module sc_in signals and allow multiple core modules to drive sc_out signals of the wrapper (one driver per sc_out).
I know the port-port binding are allowed however I insist on using sc_signal as a go in-between because I have particular naming conventions on my wrapper/modules, using sc_signal would allow me to preserve both.
This should be doable quite easily, Verilog would allow this using a wire. However I was unable to find much about this online.
Basically I would like to do this (syntax is very rough):
--------------- Somewhere in Wrapper ------
sc_signal<bool> m1_sig_in_s;
sc_signal<bool> m0_sig_in_s;
sc_in<bool> port_in;
sc_out<bool> port_out;

m0_sig_in_s(port_in);
m1_sig_in_s(port_in);
port_out(m0_sig_out_s);

m0.in(m0_sig_in_s);
m0.out(m0_sig_out_s);

m1.in(m1_sig_in_s);
---------------- END 
---------------- Somewhere in Top level ----- 
sc_signal<bool> clock;
sc_signal<bool> result;

wrapper.port_in(clock);
wrapper.port_out(result);

// Do stuff to drive clock and result signals //
---------------- END 

Again, I know I could do port-port binds and bind port_in directly to m0.in and m1.in etc. However there should be an easy way to do what I'm showing in systemC right?
A previous question (Driving an sc_out from an sc_signal) also tries something similar, however with no conclusive answer.
P.S. I know I could probably use some variation of read/write to achieve this as well, but that would be very verbose for something (that I see as) very simple.

There is not a simple way to connect multiple signals to the input port.
The syntax for binding ports and signals is:
  port(signal)

That means to bind your two signals to a single port would look like this:
  port_in(m0_sig_in_s);
  port_in(m1_sig_in_s);

Unfortunately, this does not work because ports like sc_in can only have one binding.
The usual solution is to use an sc_method for the connectivity:
SC_CTOR(mymod) {
  SC_METHOD(connect_port_in);
  sensitive << port_in;
}
...
void connect_port_in() {
  m0_sig_in_s.write(port_in.read());
  m1_sig_in_s.write(port_in.read());
}

Another option is to create a custom port type that can accept more than one binding. An example can be found here:
Is it possible to bind the output of a submodule to two different output ports?
